# Picker SelectedItem and two different DB Tables

Tags: sqlite, xamarin

I've been struggling with this for a bit, and can't seem to find a solution.
I have a Picker that displays a list of college terms. Binding it isn't the issue.
I also have a table of college courses. Each course needs to be attached to a specified term.
I have set the SelectedItem to a Property of the Terms table through the SelectedIndexChanged event.
On a separate page, I want to display the SelectedItem from the previous page and the list of college course attached to that term. Right now, the new page displays all the terms (with the name changed to the SelectedItem, and all the courses, regardless of which term they are attached to (through TermId).

I figured this would need to be done with a SQLite query using an inner join, but I can't seem to set the ListView ItemsSouce to that results of that query (even using `ToList();`), and am not even sure if thats something I should be doing.

I also thought about creating a new table, and inserting the values of the query into that table and binding it that way.

Any advice on the best way to accomplish this?

Terms table:

```
 public class Terms
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string TermName { get; set; } 
        public string TermStatus { get; set; } 
        public DateTime TProjStart { get; set; }
        public DateTime TProjEnd { get; set; } 
        public DateTime TActStart { get; set; } 
        public DateTime TActEnd { get; set; }
        public string Pick { get; set; }
    }
```

Courses Table:

```
public class Courses
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string CourseName { get; set; }
        public string CourseStatus { get; set; }
        public DateTime CourseStart { get; set; }
        public DateTime CourseEnd { get; set; }
        public string InstructName { get; set; }
        public string InstructEmail { get; set; }
        public string InstructPhone { get; set; }
        public string Notes { get; set; }
        public int TermId { get; set; }

    }
```

The TermId is supposed to reference Terms.Id as a sort of foreignkey, but I can't seem to actually make it a foreignkey, so I was thinking I may need to manually set it.
Picker SelectedIndexChanged event:

```
public void termPicker_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(App.DatabaseLocation))
            {
                var pick = (Terms)termPicker.SelectedItem;

                if (termPicker.SelectedItem != null)
                {
                    conn.Execute($"UPDATE Terms SET Pick ='{pick.TermName}'");

                }
                else
                {
                    var refresh = new Page1();
                    Navigation.InsertPageBefore(refresh, this);
                    Navigation.PopAsync();

                }
```

Comment: is the Picker just supposed to filter the items that are shown on the next page?  If so, then shouldn't you just pass the value of the selected item to the next page?  I don't understand what the purpose of doing the `Update` is?

Comment: @Jason My intent was to update the Terms table Pick property to the SelectedItem. Then from the next page use that property in a Label binding. As far as passing the SelectedItem i'm not entirely sure how to do that so ill do some research. However, I'll still need to find a way to attached the courses to the term. I'm not sure if setting the Courses.TermId to the Term.Id is the way to go, or even how to display those courses by TermId.

Comment: @Jason Ok was able to pass the value, and its displaying correctly. Now just need to figure out a way to display only the courses attached to the selected term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now just need to figure out a way to display only the courses attached
>   to the selected term

```
var courses = db.Table<Courses>().Where(c => c.TermId == selectedTerm).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks! That seems to be working, sort of. It pulls the list of all the courses attached to terms like expected (I did have to change it up a little `var courses = db.Table<Courses>().ToList().Where(c => c.TermId == terms.Id);` However, I can't seem to extract specific columns (i.e. CourseName) from that list.
Thanks for all your help! I'll keep looking!

Comment: `courses` should be a `List<Course>` so you should be able to access properties of any individual item in the list

Comment: I can't seem to get it. I can set courses as the listview ItemSource no issues, but it only displays the namespace and model. But then trying to set a label as CourseName using courseText.Text = courses.CourseName;' returns a CourseName not found error. I tried setting it from '.Where' to '.String' and only get true or false.

Comment: `courses` is a List of courses so it has no CourseName property.  Only individual items in the list have a CourseName property.

Comment: Ok so I need to specify the index first, then the CourseName property. Something like 'courseText.Text = courses.[0].CourseName;' Or for each item in the list use a foreach statement to get all the items and the CourseName property?

Comment: Yes, but if you are using courses as an ItemsSource then you can just bind to "CourseName" in your template

Comment: I had tried that, but it didn't display anything. Just tried again with ViewCell and it worked. Thanks